# let concourse job only triggered by git merge commit

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

I'm working on a pipeline, which watches a git repo and trigger some job when there's a commit. But the repo has too many commits, and I just want the merge commit trigger update, and all other commits should be ignored.
The concourse git resourse seems doesn't provide this function. 
https://github.com/concourse/git-resource

Answer (score 0):

That's right, it doesn't. It wouldn't be impossible to implement, though; you could simply modify the git-resource to loop through all the commits since the commit the previous check script found and if there are any that have two parents, trigger on that. Pull requests are always welcome!